# activiti - Terminate running process instance

Tags: activiti, business-process-management

I've a porcess running in Activiti which consists of only service tasks. The porcess is long running and on some occasions I would like to terminate it mid way. Process is started using

```
ProcessInstance pi = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(
                processDefinitionId, executionParameters);
```

From the [activiti forum](https://forums.activiti.org/content/terminating-process-instance-along-awaiting-user-tasks), processes can be terminated by calling

```
void deleteProcessInstance(String processInstanceId, String deleteReason);
```

on `runtimeService`.

The problem is that the `startProcessInstanceById` method only returns after the execution has finished. So I don't get the `processInstance` unless process has ended.

However, I did debug the code and I'm able to find out the `processInstanceId` in the implementation of [`JavaDeleate#execute()`](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/delegate/JavaDelegate.html#execute-org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution-) method.

Now when I invoke `runtimeService.deleteProcessInstance(processInstanceId, deleteReason)` method from a different thread, I get `ActivitiObjectNotFoundException` stating that the given processInstanceId dosn't exist.

Furthermore, when the processInstance is running, invoking `runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().list()` returns a blank list even though the process is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void deleteProcessInstance(String processInstanceId, String deleteReason);
```

uses processInstanceId which is present only in the case when transaction is committed. (see [transactions in activiti](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#bpmnConcurrencyAndTransactions))
I did not test whether it is possible to delete currently running process instance, but I would expect some kind of exception there (running process instance is referencing deleted execution)

In your case, I would add flag to indicate whether process has to be terminated. This flag can be checked in e.g. listener during process instance execution. If you do not want to make your process model messy you can add the listener to the model automatically (see [Hooking into process parsing](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#_hooking_into_process_parsing)).

Comment: Martin has the right answer here. Use a Parse Handler to automatically add a listener to each service task that will terminate the instance on the activity boundary (either on complete or create events). You will not be able to use the REST API or standard Java process instance terminate or delete calls as you never actually hit the database with your "Straight through process".

Answer (score 1):

Process is commited to database once it reaches asynchronous point in every execution. Other threads will not see your process before that time.

Simplest way to reveal your process is to make its first step asynchronous. That way calling thread will get control back as soon as process is created. In this case jobexecutor will continue work on process from asynchronous point (Web request context will be lost. If you need one, you'll have to pass it to process as, for example, process variables). You'll need to make polling for results or use other synchronisation mechanics in this case if you want to return process result immediately.

I'm not sure in this case deleteProcess will actually always delete process, there is possibility to encounter db locking exceptions. But you can do all the work in subprocess with bounding interrupting signalCatchingEvent that will probably cancel your process instantly.

Answer (score -1):

To generate a process instance ID after start, use this code in script
execution:

```
forceUpdate();
```